# Errors in executing javascript with perl Selenium::Remote::Driver

Tags: javascript, perl, selenium-webdriver, dom

I am exploring [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) - specifically running javascript.

However, in running this - which I think is pretty much the example in the documentation page:

```
use FindBin          qw( $RealBin );
use Selenium::Chrome qw( );

$\ = "\n"; $, = "\t"; 

my $web_driver = Selenium::Chrome->new(
   binary => "/usr/bin/chromedriver",
);

print $web_driver->has_javascript;

$web_driver->get($ARGV[0]);

my $script = q{
       var arg1 = arguments[0];
       var elem = window.document.findElementById(arg1);
      return elem;
   };
my $elem = $web_driver->execute_script($script,'hnmain');
print $elem;
```

I get this error:

```
Error while executing command: javascript error: javascript error: window.document.findElementById is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.216) at /home/simone/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 411.
 at /home/simone/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 361.
```

Why is that? what am I doing wrong?

The line with `print $web_driver->has_javascript;`prints a true value.

Comment: Re "*The line with print `$web_driver->has_javascript;` prints a true value.*", There's no doubt that the JavaScript *is* running. It did `var arg1 = arguments[0];` without error and died doing `window.document.findElementById`. Documents have no such method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
findElementById
```

should be

```js
getElementById
```

[Mozilla's documentation of the Document DOM object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)

Comment: Just when you thought copy-pasting from the documentation would work... Thanks, I should have gotten that

Comment: oh dang! yeah, I see that. Send bug report?